# managing bash script security in or above the html directory

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, bash, security

The company I work for utilizes a highly highly customized wordpress installation.  I have written a custom plugin to take care of video conversion and encoding using ffmpeg.  The plugin executes a bash script to utizilie ffmpeg, convert the videos, and then edit the relevant database tables to reflect the changes.

I have kept the necessary bash scripts in the same plugin folder for management and version tracking purposes, but I notice now that there are security flaws with this.  If someone enters the url manually they can read the bash scripts.

I have been fiddling around with ownership/permissions settings to try and make it so that the scripts will still execute but users cannot see them, but I cannot get this to work.  By default the scripts have an owner and group of an arbitrary user by apache (default:defult) and permissions setting 755.  I've tried setting all other sorts of permissions (root:default 751 as an example) to try and make it so that users cannot read the scripts but will still execute.

I could put the scripts below the html home directory, and they would work just fine, but then these would be more complicated to manage, update and deploy across all our sites (we have about 5 with an identical codebase but are likely to have many may more in weeks and months to come).

Does anyone out there know what the permissions/ownership should be so that I can keep the bash scripts in the plugin directory, where they will execute properly but be unreadable?  or does anyone have another idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

1. Hide the scripts with an .htaccess (put them into a separate folder)

   ```
   RedirectMatch 404 .*
   ```

   Add crontab entries which call PHP scripts (like in every minute). They would fetch tasks from a database table and call the shell scripts with proper parameters.
2. If you want to make them callable, then put them into a subfolder and hide them with the above htaccess file. Then create PHP files, which have authentication (like basic HTTP auth), and in case of successful authentication they would call the shell scripts, passing the parameters they got.